# Adding a getAs[T] method to Map

Tags: scala

I would like to add a `getAs[T](key)` method to `Map`, that would return the value `asInstanceOf[T]`, which I find useful when the value type is `Any`. This is my attempt using trait.

```
trait MapT extends Map[Any, Any] {
  def getAs[T](key: Any): T = super.apply(key).asInstanceOf[T]
}
val map = new Map[Any,Any] with MapT
```

But, the compiler wouldn't let me do this since the `+`, `-`, `iterator` and `get` methods are not defined, which I really don't want to define.

How do I go about doing this? Is there a better approach to `getAs[T]` ?

Comment: You can of course manage this with pimp / enrich technique, but you should consider carefully whether you want to turn Scala, a language in which types can work _so_ hard for you and turn it into a lowly dynamically typed language where all the burden of keeping track of what's what and where it is falls upon the programmer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go with enrich-my-library pattern (former pimp-my-library):

```
class MapT(underlying: Map[Any,Any]) {
  def getAs[T](key: Any): T = underlying.apply(key).asInstanceOf[T]
}

implicit def map2MapT(m: Map[Any,Any]) = new MapT(m)
```

Now all you need is to keep map2MapT imported where you want getAs to be used.

In scala 2.10 you can made use of so-named *implicit classes* and write the same as:

```
implicit class MapT(underlying: Map[Any,Any]) {
      def getAs[T](key: Any): T = underlying.apply(key).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

If you don't want to produce wrappers, you can use another 2.10 feature -- *value class*:

```
implicit class MapT(val underlying: Map[Any,Any]) extends AnyVal {
      def getAs[T](key: Any): T = underlying.apply(key).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

So compiler will cut MapT class and leave getAs[T] method inlined at every call site.

Comment: For the value class example, doesn't `underlying` need to be a `val`? I seem to remember something about "value class = exactly one val parameter"...?